# How to search for multiple terms using AND in a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple web app listing different data types in searchable tables.

I'm using MySQL for the database.

For example, there's a list of Employees with FirstName, LastName, and so on.

Example `Employees` table:

```
ID  | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME     | EMAILADDRESS
---------------------------------------------
001 | John      | Smith        | js@gmail.com
002 | John      | Jones        | jj@gmail.com
003 | Michael   | Smith        | ms@gmail.com
004 | Betty     | Taylor-Smith | bts@gmail.com
```

There's a simple text field for searches.

Search for `John Smith` results are anything has a `John` AND `Smith` in it:

```
001 | John      | Smith
```

Search for `John`, results are anything that has `John` in it:

```
001 | John      | Smith
002 | John      | Jones
```

Search for `Smith`, results are anything that has `Smith` in it:

```
001 | John      | Smith
003 | Michael   | Smith
004 | Betty     | Taylor-Smith
```

So ... my question is ... how should I write the SQL query for this?

```
select * from employees where ...
```

If I search for `John Smith` ...

```
((firstname like "%John%") OR (firstname like "%Smith%")) 
AND 
((lastname like "%John%") OR (lastname like "%Smith%"));
AND 
((emailaddress like "%John%") OR (emailaddress like "%Smith%"));
```

Returns zero results because the `emailaddress` doesn't match.

If I change ANDs to ORs ...

```
((firstname like "%John%") OR (firstname like "%Smith%")) 
OR 
((lastname like "%John%") OR (lastname like "%Smith%"));
OR 
((emailaddress like "%John%") OR (emailaddress like "%Smith%"));
```

Then I get all four results because there's a `John` or a `Smith` in every row ... which is not the result I want, I only want the first row 001.

```
001 | John      | Smith        | js@gmail.com
002 | John      | Jones        | jj@gmail.com
003 | Michael   | Smith        | ms@gmail.com
003 | Betty     | Taylor-Smith | bts@gmail.com
```

How should I approach this SQL query?

Comment: Would be quite easy in Postgres: `select e.*
from employee e
where e::text like '%John%'
  or e::text like '%Smith%'`

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting.  What's is that syntax "e.*" called?  I'll google to learn more about it, and see if there's a MySQL alternative.

Comment: The `e.*` is a standard table alias reference and not relevant here. The trick is the `e::text` which converts the whole **row** into a single (comma delimited) string on which the `LIKE` operator is applied. I don't think MySQL can do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want:

```
((firstname LIKE "%John%") OR (lastname LIKE "%John%") OR (emailaddress LIKE "%John%")) 
AND 
((firstname LIKE "%Smith%") OR (lastname LIKE "%Smith%") OR (emailaddress LIKE "%Smith%"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you potentially use [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) to meet your requirements?

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE CONCAT_WS(" ", firstname, lastname) LIKE "%John Smith%"
OR firstname LIKE "%John Smith%" # in case user provides just a first name
OR lastname LIKE "%John Smith%" # in case user provides just a last name
OR emailaddress LIKE "%John Smith%" # support searching by e-mail at the same time
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I didn't know about CONCAT_WS that will come in handy in the future.  For now @Aioros answer is what I needed, but thanks for the help!

Comment: My pleasure! @Aioros' solution will likely work best for your use case regardless.